# How about questions already answered without being duplicates?

Tags: feature-request

When closing a question, there is the option to label it as a duplicate, and while that results in a useful "This question already has an answer here" in the current context, even if the link provided points to a specific answer, it looks like it ends up redirecting to the question, not the particular answer.

In the case of an already existing answer to a question that is not a duplicate, it may not necessarily be the accepted or sole (and obvious) answer. So I think that "already answered" might be a good addition to "duplicate of" while redirecting to a particular answer rather than a question as the means to propose a particular answer from a question that is not a direct duplicate. It is not really a game changer, but it is a convenient way to specify which particular answer you think applies to the question.

Comment: You can always add a comment pointing to a specific answer.

Comment: @Glorfindel - nobody argues that you can't, however that's just a hint unlike closing the question as a duplicate. So it could likely attract parasitic repost answers.

Comment: @ddriver If someone posts a low quality repost then downvote it.  It's that easy.

Comment: @Servy you are still missing the point, but I get it, people resent change ;)

Comment: It's ok to resent change if you believe it wouldn't provide any improvement to the site.

Comment: @Pekka웃 take the beliefs and bring them to the church. It doesn't look like SO is about beliefs, it looks like it is about factual knowledge, and being able to stir it straight to the point is practically and factually beneficial, there is no need to believe, just to think objectively.

Comment: So basically, your suggestion is *factually* and *objectively* good, and people here just aren't objective enough to see it? I'm afraid such is the fate of many a great idea.

Comment: Only if you are capable of conceiving that being specifically helpful is objectively better than being vaguely helpful. I dare say I am capable of objectivity, I've spent quite a lot of time learning how to see past my own nose :) Judging by the popular reaction, an ability as rare as a hen's teeth :D

Comment: In this case the popular opinion is the correct one, your opinion is simply wrong. But clearly from your patronising, condescending, even rude response to everyone here (the smileys are fooling no one), you just aren't capable of conceiving that point. Never mind.

Comment: @Clive - now that 's sound argumentation, if it is popular then its right, and vice versa. The smileys are very much sincere and go hand in hand with the sarcasm and cynicism you mistake for rudeness ;) I saw room for improvement in the functionality and offered it publicly, and it got "booed" and rejected long before the stubbornness and inability to see the obvious toggled my cynicism, but I will not go into details on herd behavior as it will likely be interpreted as more rudeness by the popular kids ;) So whatever

Comment: Correlation my friend, not causation. The popular opinion isn't right because it's popular in this case, it's right because it's right. Anyway, I've seen how you "argue" so not getting involved any further. Im sure you'll need to get the last word in, so be my guest and reply to this anyway

Comment: @Clive well how could I reject such a "friendly" invitation. Not to argue however, just to deconstruct that last paragraph. Throwing the word "friend" around like that sure makes you that much of a nice fella, nothing is "right because it is right" - it is a logical paradox. To be right takes argumentation, and so far I haven't seen not one CON that illustrated anything other than failure and unwillingness to get the point. As for the "last word in" - that was a good one, you deserve a treat for it. Cuz if I don't, then "you showed me", and if I do I am trol obligated to have it ;) Precious!!!

Comment: I'm not sure what the problem is - you made a (perfectly reasonable) suggestion; it was rejected by the majority of people here, also for perfectly reasonable reasons, using the accepted way of rejecting suggestions (downvoting). It happens to the best of us, [including the site's founder.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/users/1/jeff-atwood?tab=answers&sort=votes&page=145) If you can't handle that without getting into nonsense about herd mentality, "unwillingness to get the point" and such, you probably shouldn't post suggestions here.

Answer (score 7):

We don't *want* to point to an answer.  We want to point to the whole question.  If better answers come along, or if the community opinion of the answers changes users being directed there should be seeing those changes, rather than be directed to an answer that isn't considered the best answer to that question.

Comment: My point is that a narrow scope question might be entirely covered by an answer to a wider scope question. There might be a number of answers to such a question, so it would be helpful to specify which is the relevant one.

Comment: @ddriver If the narrow question is a duplicate, obviously all of them which deserve an upvote...

Comment: @Deduplicator - it is about being specific - "how to build a birdhouse" is not a duplicate of "how to hammer a nail" even if the latter fully covers the former. And don't take the figurative example too literally.

Comment: @ddriver then you shouldn't be closing such questions as duplicates.

Comment: @Servy - well DO'H welcome to the point, which is to close questions as already answered without being duplicates. It is already answered proficiently, it is not a duplicate, any more answers would be redundant duplicates or copies.

Comment: Either all good answers answer the duplicate, in which case there's no reason to link to one in particular, or they don't, and the question shouldn't be closed as a duplicate.

Comment: Not if it is a specific. I mean if all the answers cover the same material, they should be seen as redundant and donwvoted, IMO the only good reason to add an answer to an already answered question is if you have something to add, which might be just it.

Comment: @ddriver If you have good examples of questions that aren't duplicates but are answered the same way, please add them to [my attempt at collecting these](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/267318/are-there-any-non-trivial-examples-of-exact-duplicate-answers-to-non-duplicate-q). I strongly doubt that there's any significant population of these, but would appreciate counterarguments.

Comment: @ddriver What does that have to do with this?  Yes, you should only post an answer if you have something to add, but you still need to *answer the question* for it to be a good answer.

Comment: Often such posts fill in gaps left from the already existing answers.

Comment: @ddrivet that would be a comment, not  answer.

Comment: @Servy - "should" != "would" - many times it is not, and happens to contain information relevant to subsequent questions. Aside from the comment length limit, I actually can recall quite a lot of "addition" answers which have have more upvotes than the accepted answer. But be my guest, walk through all of those and convert them to comments, and don't forget to split the longer ones into consecutive comments.

Comment: @ddriver So you're saying that we need to completely re-write how duplicate questions work because some people post non-answers and answers and we need to be able to close questions as duplicates of those non-answers, instead of duplicates of other actual questions with actual answers?  No.  If *actual* answers to a question in no way answers a question you're looking at, but it has a non-answer that answers it, then it's just not a duplicate.

Comment: So I am saying you continue missing the point hard. There are no duplicate questions at hand here, that much should be obvious. Duplicate question is not the same as already answered question, a good answer can easily exist as a part of an answer to a question which is not a duplicate... Sorry if I don't continue repeating that simple concept in the future, but at this point I feel like explaining particle physics to a particle, and I don't like it.

Comment: @ddriver So I am saying you continue missing the point hard.  The fact remains that you're proposing creating a brand new feature to help support people who are violating the rules and posting content that merits deletion.  If someone posts a completely off topic post to a question that doesn't answer that question, but that would *actually* answer some other question, the solution is to post the answer to the question it actually answers, not to try to close the question as a duplicate of the question it doesn't answer and link to the answer.

Comment: You are insinuating products of your imagination. I am talking about an  answer contained within an already existing on-topic answer to a broader question which is not a practical duplicate. Is it too much to grasp?

Comment: @ddriver *You* were the one *specifically* saying that these are posts that aren't answering the question, and *you* were the one saying that they're off topic tangents.  Sounds like you should go read your own comments for the first time, as you clearly haven't done so until now.

Comment: You keep on stepping up with the absurdities, now you are putting words in my mouth? Keep up the "good work" lol. Or maybe step up with improving your skills in understanding simple logic and common sense. I never meant, said or even attempt to imply that, how you got to such a conclusion is a complete mystery, but hopefully you will humor me. I've actually been quite specific on the subject, but judging by your reactions, "specific" might not be your thing.

Comment: @ddriver Thanks for confirming that you don't even know what you've said yourself.  Since apparently you can't be bothered to know what you've said, I'll just have to quote it.  Me: "you still need to answer the question for it to be a good answer." You: "Often such posts fill in gaps left from the already existing answers" Me: "that would be a comment, not answer" You: "'should' != 'would' - many times it is not" So you're *specifically* stating that you're talking about comments posted as answers that *don't answer the question* but instead post tangentially related information.

Comment: Well, thanks for confirming that you don't even know the difference between answering and commenting. When existing answers are lacking in useful detail people post that as an answer - you can see that everywhere, and there is a good reason for it - because it is an actual answer to a question, not a comment on an answer or a question, because comments are not the proper format to display information - they are limited in length, cannot be edited and revisioned to reflect updates, and can't be properly formatted. Comments are for commenting, not for providing more detailed answers...

Comment: What also happens often is that different answers provide fundamentally different solutions to a given problem, and some of those solutions can be applicable to other problems as well. And once again, you already have an answer to a question, but you can't really specify it as such, you can only close the question as a duplicate to a question which is NOT actually a duplicate, and you can't really specific the actual answer that applies. It is very surprising that you are still unable to see how "already answered" would make a good addition to "duplicate of".

Comment: @ddriver Well, thanks for confirming that you don't even know the difference between answering and commenting.  Just because you put a comment in the answer box doesn't make it an answer to the question.  Answers aren't for comments that need more formatting than comments provide, they're for *answers to the question*.  It's specifically against the rules to post comments as answers.  Yes, it's possible to post an answer that answers the question, just in a different way than other answers.  But you specifically said you were talking about answers that **don't answer the question**.

Answer (score 0):

If an answer to non-duplicate question happens to answer this question it *does not* mean this question is duplicate.

Proper actions in that case could be:

- downvote (if finding the answer is obvious),
- answer linking to existing question/answer for extended explanation
- editing this/duplicate target questions to be a bit broader so one can be closed as duplicate of another

Some guidance on types of duplicates: [Duplicate question (but only when you know the answer)?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/258804/duplicate-question-but-only-when-you-know-the-answer)